# Retrieve one row from set result if value in certain column is duplicate

Tags: mysql

I would like to retrieve one record from table if there is duplicate in certain column like it follows:

```
------------------------
| id | year |  number  | 
| 1  | 2018 |    I     |
| 1  | 2018 |    II    |
| 1  | 2017 |    I     |
| 1  | 2016 |    II    |
| 2  | 2017 |    I     |
| 2  | 2017 |    II    |
| 2  | 2016 |    I     |
| 2  | 2016 |    II    |
| 2  | 2015 |    II    |
------------------------

desired output

------------------------
| id | year |  number  | 
| 1  | 2018 |    I     |
| 1  | 2017 |    I     |
| 1  | 2016 |    II    |
| 2  | 2017 |    I     |
| 2  | 2016 |    I     |
| 2  | 2015 |    II    |
------------------------
```

I've googled and tried tricks with 'group by + having' and tried creating index on those columns with 'insert ignore' combined but without avail. Anyone to say if this is even possible?

**UPDATE:**
Finally came up with solution, I've created index on `id` and `year`, then made copy of existing table with 'INSERT IGNORE INTO ...'.

Comment: Is there any primary key defined for table ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use aggregation for your required data set as

```
select id, `year`, min(`number`)
from your_table
group by id, `year`
order by id,`year` desc
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c94fc/4)

> [MIN()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) may take a string argument; in such cases, it returns the minimum string value

Comment: yeah dude, it seems to me like that did the trick! I'll check it out more precisely..

Answer (score 0):

**you can try this to select unique values from table**

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2,.....columnN 
FROM table_name
```

> Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP BY id,`year`;`

Note: it is not good practice to create tables without primary keys and use MySQL keywords for table names, such as year and number.
If you still insist on using year and number always encapsulate them with `.